# get document from a html file which is not linked to the javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i have a JS file with a function named "login" . I also have a html file but the JS cant be linked via `<script>` because it would destory the purpose of my script. The JS gets executed via server.
Now i wanted to write :`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', login);` but i cant use `document` because there is no document the JS could access.

Now my question is, if it is possible to access the document of a html file altought the JS isnt attached to it?

Comment: Do you mean you're running the JS on the server with node.js?

Comment: The server has no access to the document on the client.

Comment: yes with node js via express...its running on localhost

Comment: It is really not clear what you're describing here.  Are the javascript file and the HTML file both on the server?  Is the user loading the HTML file and you want the javascript to run along with it, or are they loading the javascript file and you want it to somehow reference the HTML page?

Comment: `node.js` is a preprocessor, meaning all of the necessary code is ran before the page is returned to the front-end. In order to run code afterwards, you would have to have some code on the front end to either run the process or trigger something on the backend by sending another request through ajax, XHR, or WebSockets depending on the situation.

Comment: yes they are both on the server....i want the JS function to execute when the html page loads

Comment: Then you need to link to it from the HTML file. I'm guessing  the reason you don't want to do that is because it contains your authentication code and you don't want people to find and inspect it.... if that's correct you'll need to change to a serverside approach, there is no safe way to handle authentication via clientside javascript.

Comment: No thats not the reason...The reason is that i dont want to execute the whole JS code like "var loggedIn = false;" .I dont want it to run the code which isnt in a function...I only want the run the login function if the Html site loads

Comment: @Timo you can use lazy loading to grab a piece of JS code after the page loads, fetching the content of the JS file (with only the function you want) and attaching it to the DOM, not that this will avoid tempering the file, but will only fetch the function after the page is loaded.